Read gmail using Auth2.0 in Springboot (Java 17)
I want to implement google's auth2.0 for security to read my gmail. So far it works well with the normal email and app password. But I am getting a invalid credentials error when auth2.0 access token is introduced. What am I doing wrong?
Credential credential = gmailOAuth2Config.authorize();
String oauthToken = credential.getAccessToken();

String oauth2Token = "user=" + gmailEmail + "\u0001auth=Bearer " + oauthToken + "\u0001\u0001";
String base64AuthString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(oauth2Token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println("Encoded SASL XOAUTH2 Token: " + base64AuthString);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");

Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");
//Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps"); works!


try {
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", gmailEmail, base64AuthString );
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", gmailEmail, gmailPassword);//works
    System.out.println("Connected successfully to Gmail IMAP.");
} catch (jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException e) {
    System.err.println("Authentication failed: " + e.getMessage());
}

2024-11-14T10:12:19.207+05:30 ERROR 11772 --- [emailservice] [   scheduling-1] c.d.emailservice.service.EmailService    : An error occurred while reading email inbox: Not connected

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.checkConnected(IMAPStore.java:1960) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.getFolder(IMAPStore.java:1737) ~[jakarta.mail-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.doxmate.emailservice.service.EmailService.readEmail(EmailService.java:97) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at 


try wiht  token, not base64AuthString, store.connect("imap.gmail.com", gmailEmail, oauthToken);

Already did. Not working
